# Iterating over multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

```
##1    
M_members = [1000 , 1450, 1900]  
M = pd.DataFrame(M_members)

##2
a_h_members = [0.4 , 0.6 , 0.8 ]
a_h = pd.DataFrame(a_h_members) 

##3
d_h_members = [0.1 , 0.2 ]
d_h = pd.DataFrame(d_h_members)
```

As the output I want is in dataframe form:

```
1000 0.4 0.1
1000 0.4 0.2
1000 0.6 0.1
1000 0.6 0.2
1000 0.8 0.1
1000 0.8 0.2
1450 0.4 0.1
1450 0.4 0.2
1450 0.6 0.1
1450 0.6 0.2
1450 0.8 0.1
1450 0.8 0.2
1900 0.4 0.1
1900 0.4 0.2
1900 0.6 0.1
1900 0.6 0.2
1900 0.8 0.1
1900 0.8 0.2
```

I want to do this loop for more dataframes actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your data size, [expand_grid](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.expand_grid.expand_grid) from `pyjanitor` may help with performance:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor as jn
import pandas as pd

others = {'a':M, 'b':a_h, 'c':d_h}
jn.expand_grid(others = others)

       a    b    c
       0    0    0
0   1000  0.4  0.1
1   1000  0.4  0.2
2   1000  0.6  0.1
3   1000  0.6  0.2
4   1000  0.8  0.1
5   1000  0.8  0.2
6   1450  0.4  0.1
7   1450  0.4  0.2
8   1450  0.6  0.1
9   1450  0.6  0.2
10  1450  0.8  0.1
11  1450  0.8  0.2
12  1900  0.4  0.1
13  1900  0.4  0.2
14  1900  0.6  0.1
15  1900  0.6  0.2
16  1900  0.8  0.1
17  1900  0.8  0.2
```

You can drop a column level, or flatten it:

```py
jn.expand_grid(others = others).droplevel(axis = 1, level = 1)

       a    b    c
0   1000  0.4  0.1
1   1000  0.4  0.2
2   1000  0.6  0.1
3   1000  0.6  0.2
4   1000  0.8  0.1
5   1000  0.8  0.2
6   1450  0.4  0.1
7   1450  0.4  0.2
8   1450  0.6  0.1
9   1450  0.6  0.2
10  1450  0.8  0.1
11  1450  0.8  0.2
12  1900  0.4  0.1
13  1900  0.4  0.2
14  1900  0.6  0.1
15  1900  0.6  0.2
16  1900  0.8  0.1
17  1900  0.8  0.2
```

Comment: what do you mean 'depending data size'? Is expand_grid suitable for large data, I mean  dataframe which having 1000 rows?

Comment: How can I write the output of "jn.expand_grid(others = others)" as a dataframe?

Comment: @GTek the output is a dataframe. What output are you getting

Comment: @sammywemmy I cannnot name the output. Can I do something like that; 
A=jn.expand_grid(others = others) print(A)

Comment: Yes you can @GTek

Comment: @sammywemmy in this dataframe form how can I reach the rows of the dataframe? (0 , 1, ,,,,17)

Comment: Now I am confused... What does your output look like? Are you running it in a jupyter notebook?

Comment: @sammywemmy I am running in spyder.                                                                 
It is in dataframe form, I want to reach the item at A[0][a] = 1000, I cannot do this.

Comment: I think I get what you mean ... try this : ``A = jn.expand_grid(others = others).droplevel(axis = 1, level = 1)``; then the next step, on another line, should be `A.loc[0, 'a']` ...

Comment: @sammywemmy Thanks a lot! One more and the last question, can I do 'A.loc[0, 'a']' this in a for loop for rows?

Comment: you probably can; I'd avoid running a for loop on the rows; it is possible that there is something more efficient

Comment: @sammywemmy  Could you please tell me if there is a more efficient way instead of for loop?

Comment: it'd be better if you asked it as a new question so others can chime in and proffer solutions. Kindly add your existing solution so others can use that as a yardstick and suggest better options, if any.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
>>> import itertools
>>> pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(*[M_members, a_h_members, d_h_members]))
```

---

```
       0    1    2
0   1000  0.4  0.1
1   1000  0.4  0.2
2   1000  0.6  0.1
3   1000  0.6  0.2
4   1000  0.8  0.1
5   1000  0.8  0.2
6   1450  0.4  0.1
7   1450  0.4  0.2
8   1450  0.6  0.1
9   1450  0.6  0.2
10  1450  0.8  0.1
11  1450  0.8  0.2
12  1900  0.4  0.1
13  1900  0.4  0.2
14  1900  0.6  0.1
15  1900  0.6  0.2
16  1900  0.8  0.1
17  1900  0.8  0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting from the DataFrames, you can use a repeated cross merge:

```
dfs = [M, a_h, d_h]

from functools import reduce

out = (reduce(lambda a,b: a.merge(b, how='cross'), dfs)
      .set_axis(range(len(dfs)), axis=1)
      )
```

Output:

```
       0    1    2
0   1000  0.4  0.1
1   1000  0.4  0.2
2   1000  0.6  0.1
3   1000  0.6  0.2
4   1000  0.8  0.1
5   1000  0.8  0.2
6   1450  0.4  0.1
7   1450  0.4  0.2
8   1450  0.6  0.1
9   1450  0.6  0.2
10  1450  0.8  0.1
11  1450  0.8  0.2
12  1900  0.4  0.1
13  1900  0.4  0.2
14  1900  0.6  0.1
15  1900  0.6  0.2
16  1900  0.8  0.1
17  1900  0.8  0.2
```